# Unexpected cast during assignment

Tags: c++, c, casting, stm32, microprocessors

There is piece of code in stm32 library that's behaving strangely. This is assignment made from initializing structure to timer auto-reload register:

```
/* Set the Autoreload value */
TIMx->ARR = TIM_TimeBaseInitStruct->TIM_Period ;
```

I've `TIM_Period = 1999999`, however after assignment `TIMx->ARR = 33919`. Smaller number usually points to overflow, so I checked: `(1999999-33919) / 65536 = 30`. This would mean the number overflowed 30 times on 16 bit data type, but both variables are 32 bit unsigned integers. Extracted from structure declarations:

For TIMx:

```
  __IO uint32_t ARR;         /*!< TIM auto-reload register,            Address offset: 0x2C */
```

For TIM_TimeBaseInitStruct:

```
uint32_t TIM_Period;            /*!< Specifies the period value to be loaded into the active
                                     Auto-Reload Register at the next update event.
                                     This parameter must be a number between 0x0000 and 0xFFFF.  */
```

Where `__IO` is defined as `volatile`.

This is disassembly of that assignment:

```
 296        TIMx->ARR = TIM_TimeBaseInitStruct->TIM_Period ;
0800c37c:   ldr r3, [r7, #0]
0800c37e:   ldr r2, [r3, #4]
0800c380:   ldr r3, [r7, #4]
0800c382:   str r2, [r3, #44]       ; 0x2c
```

What is happening here.. could it be something external causing the value to overflow? Note that I'm debugging on real hardware through ST-Link with no code optimization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to guess that your chip has 16-bit timer registers.  That is, it might still be a 32-bit register, but only have 16 useful bits in it.

Something like:

```
 31                16 15               0
+--------------------+------------------+
|      RESERVED      | Auto-reload value|
+--------------------+------------------+
```

Fact checking forthcoming (if you have a specific part number that would help me out).

Edit:  By looking at some documentation [[PDF link](http://www.st.com/st-web-ui/static/active/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/DM00088500.pdf)], my guess seems to be confirmed:

[image]

Edit 2: Since you mentioned which chip you were using, I found that documentation too [[PDF link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWJd7.png)], which contains this handy diagram:

[image]

As you can see, some timers have 32-bit autoreload, and some don't.  Which timer you've chosen will affect the behaviour you see.

Comment: I'm going to check check in datasheets, just in case it's STM32F3-Discovery board with Cortex-M4 MCU.

Comment: The `This parameter must be a number between 0x0000 and 0xFFFF` seems to indicate that, yes. Was also looking for docs :)

Comment: Found a reference.  Updating now.

Comment: Could you please also explain, how it comes that the value can change in such way during single assignment? Does debugger re-read value from that register after assignment is made? And 'RESERVED' acts like those bits in register wouldn't be accessible, so writing on them results in discarding and reading returns zero bits, correct?

Comment: It's probably not safe to write to reserved bits in a register in the general case, but it often works the way you describe, yes.

Comment: 1999999 = 0x001E847F, because of 16-bit register is only 0x847F=33919 written.